# Как создать два FileProvider?

Tags: java, android

Для сохранения файлов внутри приложения использую FileProvider. 
В Manifest прописываю следующее:

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
            />
    </provider>
```

Ссылка на файл file_paths содержит:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="my_images" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

Еще есть файл для внешних накопителей

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Но где его надо прописать, непонятно.